# What's the meaning of "blocked_word: CG" in whois?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registrar, whois

A customer says they want to park a domain with us. In theory, they should have registered that domain already. But when I look it up with `whois`, I get this:

```
jcastro@localhost:~$ whois notactuallythedomaininquestion.br

% Copyright (c) Nic.br
%  The use of the data below is only permitted as described in
%  full by the terms of use at https://registro.br/termo/en.html ,
%  being prohibited its distribution, commercialization or
%  reproduction, in particular, to use it for advertising or
%  any similar purpose.
%  2017-11-07 09:26:29 (BRST -02:00)

% blocked_word:  CG

% Security and mail abuse issues should also be addressed to
% cert.br, http://www.cert.br/ , respectivelly to cert@cert.br
% and mail-abuse@cert.br
%
% whois.registro.br accepts only direct match queries. Types
% of queries are: domain (.br), registrant (tax ID), ticket,
% provider, contact handle (ID), CIDR block, IP and ASN.
```

What does it mean? A truly nonexistent domain doesn't give me that `blocked_word` line, instead it gives:

```
jcastro@localhost:~$ whois randomwordsalad.br
.
.
.
% No match for randomwordsalad.br
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two is that a name with "blocked word" WHOIS output can't be registered, while one with "no match" could be registered, although not being registered at that point.